# Error in converting datetime to epoch, add 5 seconds, then convert back to datetime

Tags: python, csv, datetime, epoch

I am having an issue getting a string time in a csv file to convert to epoch inside of Python. What I am trying to do long term is grab the datetime from the csv, convert to epoch, add 5 seconds, convert back to datetime, then use it as a new variable.

However, any method I try just returns a formatting error....

```
ValueError: time data '"2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%f'
```

Any help is appreciated.

I've tried out datetime.datetime, using calander,etc. All return a format error but I can't decipher what format its throwing.

Here is the entire code. The comment outs are where I'm trying to go with the code in the future. (CSV Format: datetime, IP, Email, Msg, Email)

```
import datetime, re, time
_global_path = r'C:\Users\DArthur\Documents\ITD Metrics'

with open(_global_path + '/eop_incidents.csv', 'r') as f:
    pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%f'
    find_last = (f.readlines()[-1].strip().split(','))
    net_earliest = find_last[0]  # .replace(':', '-')
    #change_to_epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(net_earliest, pattern)))


    #temp = change_to_epoch + 5
    #temp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(temp).strftime(pattern)
    #final_earliest = str(temp)


print(pattern)
#print(find_last)
print(net_earliest, type(net_earliest))
#print(change_to_epoch)



#print(temp, type(temp))
#print(final_earliest, type(final_earliest))
```

These are the results I get (Redacted for security reasons, sorry.)

%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S.%f

['"2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000"', '"IP"', '"EMAIL"', '"MSG"', '"EMAIL"']
"2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000"

What I am looking for is 2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000 to 'epoch' to 2019-04-03 09:01:18.000000.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the string into a datetime tuple, then add a timedelta to the orignal time. Like so:

```
#original string
string_time='2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000'

#Conversion
tm = datetime.datetime.strptime((string_time),  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

#Add the timedelta
future_or_past_time = tm + datetime.timedelta(seconds=4)

print future_or_past_time
>>> 2019-04-03 09:01:18
```

Where in this case, the timedelta to be added can be in seconds, hours, days etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I tried this out but I still run into a format error. (It works as a stand alone) However, I'm starting to wonder then if its a formatting problem from the CSV File. I'll look into that more, but thank you for your time and help. :)

Comment: @DenDay It's your string. It's just a case of stripping all the quotes from it and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yeah I just got that. Thanks @ajsp

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still viewing I found the issue with the formatting.

The issue was inside of the CSV File. It was returning a format of '"2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000"'. What was needed is this: '2019-04-03 09:01:14.000000'.

Note: Watch out for double quotes when formatting... :)

Comment: You should have used the CSV reader to read the file it as unquotes value when reading and quotes values when writting as needed.

Comment: @ Dan D. I tried that but it fails due to the way information is put into the CSV right now from Splunk. It's also just momentary as soon it'll be going to a DW. I'm just working on gathering pre-information to pre-fill the DW.